# Save PDF with memory stream in a list using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'd like to read an multipage pdf file from the file system and split it to separated pages. The splitted pages i like to save to an list object. The page in the list i want to save in a base64 encoded structure in a xml and send it over a rest api service.

What i have already done:

1. Read the pdf file
2. Split the pdf file to pages
3. Save the pages to a list

What's not relevant and only for completeness of my problem:

1. Send the pages with a rest api service waqsy( current no code implemented)
2. Xml structure

What's my problem?
If i save the pages from the byte array list to the file system and open the pdf (with only one page of the original page) the the **pdf file is defect and can't open**.

Which error had i made on this process?

What version of iTextSharp i use?
5.4.2

```
public List<byte[]> SplitAndSaveWithMemoryStream(string inputFilePath)
{
   // create the list
   List<byte[]> pages = new List<byte[]>();

    // get the input pdf
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath))
    {
        // iterate over the pages
        for (int pagenumber = 1; pagenumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pagenumber++)
        {
             Document document = new Document();
             MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            
             PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, memoryStream);

             document.Open();

             // copy the n-th page to the memory stream
             copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pagenumber));

             memoryStream.Position = 0;

             // save the page from the memory stream to the list
             pages.Add(memoryStream.ToArray());

             // -- TEST ---
             // save the file, only for test
             // string fullfilePath = "C://temp/temp.pdf";
             // File.WriteAllBytes(fullfilePath, pages[pagenumber]);

             document.Close();
      }

      return pages;
}
```

Xml structure:

```
<document>
  <page>
    <number>1</number>
    <content>dZwmxjwiduasmma...</content>
  </page>
  <page>
    <number>2</number>
    <content>ddiw92kjd2002jd929...</content>
  </page>
  <page>
    <number>3</number>
    <content>d82kdjEiuwowpdo...</content>
  </page>
</document>
```

Solution with the answer by 'mkl'

```
public List<byte[]> SplitAndSaveWithMemoryStream(string inputFilePath)
{
   // create the list
   List<byte[]> pages = new List<byte[]>();

    // get the input pdf
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath))
    {
        // iterate over the pages
        for (int pagenumber = 1; pagenumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pagenumber++)
        {
             Document document = new Document();
             MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            
             PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, memoryStream);

             document.Open();

             // copy the n-th page to the memory stream
             copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pagenumber));

             document.Close();

             // save the page from the memory stream to the list
             pages.Add(memoryStream.ToArray());

             // -- TEST ---
             // save the file, only for test
             // string fullfilePath = "C://temp/temp.pdf";
             // File.WriteAllBytes(fullfilePath, pages[pagenumber]);
      }

      return pages;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF in the `MemoryStream` is not finished before `document` is closed. Thus, you store incomplete PDFs.

To fix this, move

```
document.Close();
```

up right after

```
copy.AddPage(...);
```

As an aside, if I recall correctly, you don't need `memoryStream.Position = 0` before `memoryStream.ToArray()` as `ToArray` always takes the full content of the memory stream.